# Can you create your own client on Dialogflow API v2.0?

Tags: api, dialogflow-es

With the previous version of Dialogflow, when it was called api.ai, you could send a text and the bot you trained would answer with the intent of the text.
In such a way that you could create your own client, since your service would be making calls to Dialogflow.
But now many things have changed on V2.0, even though there's an API, they don't explain how to use it properly. They only explain thoroughly how to use Google Cloud which you cannot use to create your own client, since Dialogflow is the one receiving the user's input.
Could anyone throw some light here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v1 it was feasible to do this clientside.  With the way authentication works, you now will need to do this server side.  But the APIs are there... look for “detect intent” in the libraries (https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis) and the REST docs (https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent)

Comment: Thanks, navigating through their documents I landed here, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/tree/master/Dialogflow, but I can't find an example on how to use their library.
PS: Im using PHP

Comment: See the code snippet at the top of http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-dialogflow/v0.1.1/dialogflow/v2/sessionsclient